# Django Ignoring TestCases

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, django-rest-framework

There are loads of questions with this issue, but whatever I try, it just doesn't want to work. This is the file structure of my project. As you can see, all directories have an **init** file.

[image]

Here  is the code within that tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class UserManagerTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
       self.data = {
           "user": {
                "email": "normal@user.com",
                "password": "foo",
                "first_name": "Joe",
               "last_name": "Doe"
           }
       }

    def test_create_user(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        user = User.objects.create_user(**self.data['user'])
        self.assertEquals(user.email, self.data['user']['email'])
        self.assertEquals(user.first_name, self.data['user']['first_name'])
        self.assertEquals(user.last_name, self.data['user']['last_name'])
        self.assertTrue(user.is_active)
```

Indentation here is a bit messed up.

Not sure what causing the tests to be ignored. If I run the test by app namespace (python project/manage.py test project) it works fine, but If I try to run all the tests (python project/manage.py test) it says no tests are found.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming the `tests.py` file to `test_user.py` for example?

According to the documentation:

You can also provide a path to a directory to discover tests below that directory:

`$ ./manage.py test animals/`
You can specify a custom filename pattern match using the -p (or --pattern) option, if your test files are named differently from the test*.py pattern:

`$ ./manage.py test --pattern="tests_*.py"`

Comment: I tried to rename it, but that didn't make any difference. If I run the test by app name or path, it does get picked up as expected, regardless what the name of the file is. But if I run the generic test command, Django won't find my tests.